# Joomla Acymailing Subscribe Module Radio Button not centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla

Upfront, I have to say I know almost nothing about ccs and I know very little about html. However, I'm fairly proficient in Joomla. Here's my issue...

I have created an AcyMailing Module for users to enter their name and email to get a free French Lesson and click a "Get Your Free Lesson" button. The module also has a radio button to opt-in to a newsletter. For some reason, the fields for name and email and the "Get Your Free Lesson" button are all centered, but the radio button for the newsletter is to the left.

Ultimately, I need it to be something like this AND all be centered on the page...

Type in Your Name & Email to get Your Free French Lesson

Name:

Email:

[x] Subscribe to Newsletter <---------WHY IS THIS RADIO BUTTON LEFT???

Get Your Free Lesson

Note that I wasn't able to center everything in my example above. I've been trying to figure this out for hours and I know it is something simple that can be fixed easily.

Thank you,
David

Comment: A link to your live website will help, if available.

Comment: Edit the Subscribe module and under the Advanced tab, you can set the Module Alignment to "Center" if you haven't already.

Comment: Here is a link to my landing page:  http://www.thinklingo.com/french-lp-0001.   I had already set the Module Alignment in the Advanced Tab = Center. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

It may be the Acymailing css file is doing this or your template. If you can inspect the element on your live page you can then change the ccs for your elements. 
To do that for acymailing, navigate to acymailing>configuration and look in the "interface" tab. Towards the bottom there is a section called css. look at the "Module CSS File" and change the code that you found in the front end. 
If it is your site template then you do similar in that file. Not knowing what CMS you are using I cant tell you where to find that.

Comment: I don't know much about CCS. Is there a way for you to inspect the element on the URL I posted above to tell if something needs to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

Your template CSS file at `/templates/jsn_pixel_pro/css/template.css` sets the table margin as follows:

```
table {margin: 10px 0;}
```

Add the following to the end of template.css to center the check-box option line:

```
table.acymailing_lists {margin: auto;}
```

With Jooma Shine templates, it's usually best to add this code to a custom css file at `/templates/jsn_pixel_pro/css/custom.css` so future template updates don't overwrite your change. This file seems to exist on your website but is not being loaded for some reason? Maybe this needs to be enabled in the template options? Sorry, I'm not a JSN expert.